# How can I import a module's type into another module interface declaration?

Tags: flowtype

I'm trying to create a module interface declaration that uses another module's declaration, but it does not work well. Here is an MCVE. I know that I can put type annotations directly on the local modules, but I'm trying to depict what I experience with third-party modules.

.flowconfig:

```
[ignore]

[include]

[libs]
lib

[options]

[version]
^0.27.0
```

foo.js:

```
export class Foo {
  foo() {
    return 'foo';
  }
}
```

bar.js:

```
import { Foo } from './foo';

export class Bar extends Foo {
  bar() {
    return 'bar';
  }
  makeFoo() {
    return new Foo();
  }
}
```

lib/foo.js:

```
declare module './foo' {
  declare class Foo {
    foo(): string;
  }
}
```

lib/bar.js:

```
import { Foo } from './foo';
// Same result if:
// import { Foo } from '../foo';

declare module './bar' {
  declare class Bar extends Foo {
    bar(): string;
    makeFoo(): Foo;
  }
}
```

index.js:

```
/* @flow */
import { Foo } from './foo';
import { Bar } from './bar';

const bar = new Bar();
const b: number = bar.bar(); // A. wrong const type
const bf: number = bar.foo(); // B. wrong const type
bar.typo(); // C. no such method

const foo = bar.makeFoo();
foo.foo();
foo.bar();  // D. no such method
```

And `flow`'s result is:

```
index.js:6
  6: const b: number = bar.bar(); // wrong const type
                       ^^^^^^^^^ call of method `bar`
  6: const b: number = bar.bar(); // wrong const type
                       ^^^^^^^^^ string. This type is incompatible with
  6: const b: number = bar.bar(); // wrong const type
              ^^^^^^ number


Found 1 error
```

I expect 4 errors (A, B, C and D in `index.js`) but get only A. It seems that I am failing to import `Foo` properly in `lib/bar.js` so that `Foo` becomes something like a wildcard.

Is there any way to properly import a module's type into another interface declaration? Am I missing something? Any help is appreciated.

**[EDIT]**

I see some declarations in [flow-typed](https://github.com/flowtype/flow-typed) use `React$Component`, [which is declared globally](https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/v0.27.0/lib/react.js#L16), without importing it. But I'd like to use a type in a module like [`Component` in `react` module](https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/v0.27.0/lib/react.js#L214).

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you are supposed to create declarations files of your components since Flow directly use the sources. Simply `import` the classes when you need a reference to a type.

In your current example, you simply miss the `/* @flow */` on the top of your files (`bar.js`, `foo.js`).

Comment: You're right. But I'm actually trying to create declaration file for a third-party library that does not have its official declaration, and the example is an MCVE.

http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

`foo.js` and `bar.js` don't have `/* @flow */` because they are examples for third-party libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Flow does not support extending/overriding flow/lib types:

https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/396

What I've begun to do is:

1. `flow-typed install express@4.x.x`
2. Move `express_v4.x.x.js` from flow-typed/npm/ to flow-typed/ (outside flow-typed/npm/ so it won't be overwritten by future flow-typed installs, and inside flow-typed/ so flow will automatically make `declare blah` statements global)
3. Right below the `declare class express$Request...` (so it's easy to find and so it's above where it's used inside `declare module...`, I put:

   `declare class express$Request extends express$Request {
       user: any;
       isAuthenticated(): boolean;
       session: {
           loginForwardUrl: ?string;
       };
   }`

I do this instead of putting my custom props on the original class so that it's easy to see which props are custom.